# PHPUnit coverage-html analyzes the wrong folders

Tags: php, report, phpunit, code-coverage

I'm learning Zend Framework 2 after the ZF2 "[Getting Started](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/user-guide/overview.html)" tutorial. Now I have a simple application a PHPUnit test of the IndexController (the code is copied from the capitel "[Unit Testing](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/user-guide/unit-testing.html)" of the tutorial). The testing works. Now I'm trying to create a code coverage report:

```
# phpunit --coverage-html ./report
```

or

```
# phpunit --coverage-html ./report ApplicationTest/Controller/IndexControllerTest.php
```

I expect a coverage report of the whole folder `test` (first example) or the `IndexControllerTest` (second example).

What I'm currently getting is this report:

[image]

Why? And how can I make the code coverage script process the files/folders, I want to analyze.

EDIT:

I can navigate to my module folder and see the report for it:

[image]

But the questions are remaining the same: (1) Why does it work so and (2) how can I make the code coverage script process (only) the files/folders, I want to analyze.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can include/exclude files or folders for code coverage using your phpunit.xml, see the [phpunit manual](http://www.phpunit.de/manual/3.2/en/appendixes.configuration.html#appendixes.configuration.blacklist-whitelist).

Also you can ignore specific blocks of code from code coverage aggregation. See: http://www.phpunit.de/manual/3.2/en/code-coverage-analysis.html

PHPUnit code coverage is using xdebug to calculate the covered lines. If your IndexControllerTest also runs lines in order files they will show up in the coverage report as well.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Yes, it's possible to exclude some files or even folders. But why are folders `var` and `usr` displayed on the report page? How dose it look, when you create a coverage report?

Comment: Your `IndexControllerTest` also executes code in the `usr` folder. You can check which code is executed there by browsing deeper into it. If think your phpunit installation resided in the `usr` folder so this will be listed for code coverage as well, because php is running phpunit code. If you not specify any whitelist for code coverage in your configuration (phpunit.xml) phpunit will set the root for code coverage to the highest common map (`/` in your case)

Comment: Your are right, thank you!

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<phpunit bootstrap="Bootstrap.php">
 <testsuite name="zf2sandbox">
  <directory>./AlbumTest</directory>
 </testsuite>
 <filter>
  <whitelist>
   <directory suffix=".php">/var/www/sandbox/zf2sandbox/module/Album/src/Album/</directory>
  </whitelist>
 </filter>
</phpunit>`

Comment: Please remember to accept Bram's answer if it did correct your problem.